# Proof of Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability

Two players take turns flipping, independently, a fair coin, where first player starts. Game ends as second heads comes up. The player who flips the second heads wins the game. Define the event: A = "Player 1 wins game" 
Use the Law of Total Probability to prove that Pr(A) = 4/9 
  I am completely stuck here, can't even get where to start. Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: First, determine the probabilities that the first player and the second player respectively tosses the first head. Then, find the conditional probabilities that the players toss the second head, conditioned on which player tossed the first head. _Then_ apply the law of total probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tedious computational approach:

Note that the winning sequences are of the form $T^{k_1}H T^{k_2}H$, where
$k_1+k_2$ is odd if player 1 wins. 
The probability of this sequence occurring is
${1 \over 2}^{k_1+k_2+2}$.
It is straightforward to see that the probability of a sequence not being of this form is zero, so the probability of neither player winning is zero.

Let $p_k$ be the probability that player $k$ wins. We have $p_1+p_2 = 1$.

We also have
$p_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} {1 \over 2}^{2n+3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+2) {1 \over 2}^{2n+3}$, and similarly,
$p_2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1) {1 \over 2}^{2n+2}$.

Hence $p_1 = {1 \over 2} p_2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1 \over 2}^{2n+3} = {1 \over 2} p_2 +{1 \over 6}$, from which we obtain the desired result.

**Alternative**: 
I think one has to know **which** player has thrown the first head.
Let $F_k$ be the event that player $k$ throws the first head. Considerations above show that $P(F_1 \cup F_2) = 1$ and the events are clearly disjoint.

Hence 
$PA = P(A \cap F_1) + P(A \cap F_2) = P(A | F_1)P F_1 + P(A | F_2) P F_2$.

We have $F_1 = \{ T^{2n}H \}_{n \ge 0}$, $F_2 = \{ T^{2n+1}H \}_{n \ge 0}$,
and so $PF_2 = {1 \over 2} P F_1$, which lets us compute $P F_k$.

Now show $P(A | F_1) = P F_2$ and $P(A | F_2) = P F_1$ which gives
$PA = 2 P F_1 P F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the count of heads that have *already* been thrown.   We want to find $\mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=0)$

Then the first two turns can result in, 2 heads (player 2 wins), a head and a tail, or two tails.  The Law of Total Probability then sais:

$$\mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=0)
 = \frac \Box \Box\cdot 0
 + \frac \Box \Box \mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=1)
 + \frac \Box \Box \mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=0)$$

Now starting with one tail thrown, the next two turns can result in a head (immediate win for player 1), or a tail then either a head (player 2 wins) or another tail.

$$\mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=1)
 = \frac \Box \Box \cdot 1
 + \frac \Box \Box \cdot 0
 + \frac \Box \Box \mathsf P(\mathcal A\mid H=1)$$

Supply the probabilities and solve these simultaneous equations.